# Removing a specified number of lines from both head and tail of a stream

Tags: bash

```
k=$1
m=$2
fileName=$3 
head -n -$k "$fileName" | tail -n +$m
```

I have the bash code.
when I execute it, it only removes less than what it should remove. like `./strip.sh 4 5 hi.txt > bye.txt` should remove first 4 lines and last 5 lines, but it only removes first 4 lines and last "4" lines. Also, when I execute `./strip.sh 1 1 hi.txt > bye.txt`, it only removes last line, not first line....

Comment: `head -n -N` is "all but the last N lines". `tail -n +N` is "start at Nth line".

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with git ?

Comment: @123, presumably the OP is running it on Windows with the msys build of bash provided by the git package. Which is very occasionally relevant (that particular build has some bugs; for instance, process substitutions -- that is, `<()` expressions -- don't work correctly), but not very often.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough, still seems a bit of a stretch for tagging git though.

Comment: @123, I certainly agree.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -n +"$(( $1 + 1 ))" <"$3" | head -n -"$2"
```

Tested as follows:

```
set -- 4 5 /dev/stdin # assign $1, $2 and $3
printf '%s\n' {1..20} | tail -n +"$(( $1 + 1 ))" <"$3" | head -n -"$2"
```

...which correctly prints numbers between 5 and 15, trimming the first 4 from the front and 5 from the back. Similarly, with `set -- 3 6 /dev/stdin`, numbers between 4 and 14 inclusive are printed, which is likewise correct.